# How to filter query in mongoDB in collection

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongoid

I am trying to do filter in mongoDB, but I am not getting the expected output. I am using `$elemMatch` but still not getting expected out.

**Agency Collection**

```
[

  {
    "_id": "5d402d36035f3063657240ac",
    "name": "test agency",
    "msisdn": "99961110278",
    "apps": [
      {
        "pincodes": [
          "135001",
          "122018"
        ],
        "_id": "5d402d36035f3063657240ae",
        "name": "DSB"
      },
      {
        "pincodes": [
          "135001",
          "122017"
        ],
        "_id": "5d402d36035f3063657240ad",
        "name": "DBH"
      }
    ],
    "__v": 0
  }
]
```

**query on shell**

```
db.Agency.find({'apps':{$elemMatch:{name: {$regex: 'DSB', $options: 'i'} ,pincodes: { $in : ['135001','134002']}}}})
```

**getting output**

```
[
{
  "_id" : "5d401d4aba592260507479d2",
  "name" : "test agency",
  "msisdn" : "99961110278",
  "apps" : [
    {
      "pincodes" : [
        "135001",
        "122017"
      ],
      "_id" : "5d401d4aba592260507479d3",
      "name" : "DSB"
    }
  ],
  "__v" : 0
}
,
{
  "_id" : "5d402249035f3063657240a9",
  "name" : "test agency",
  "msisdn" : "99961110278",
  "apps" : [
    {
      "pincodes" : [
        "135001",
        "122017"
      ],
      "_id" : "5d402249035f3063657240ab",
      "name" : "DSB"
    },
    {
      "pincodes" : [
        "135001",
        "122017"
      ],
      "_id" : "5d402249035f3063657240aa",
      "name" : "DBH"
    }
  ],
  "__v" : 0
}
,
{
  "_id" : "5d402d36035f3063657240ac",
  "name" : "test agency",
  "msisdn" : "99961110278",
  "apps" : [
    {
      "pincodes" : [
        "135001",
        "122018"
      ],
      "_id" : "5d402d36035f3063657240ae",
      "name" : "DSB"
    },
    {
      "pincodes" : [
        "135001",
        "122017"
      ],
      "_id" : "5d402d36035f3063657240ad",
      "name" : "DBH"
    }
  ],
  "__v" : 0
}]
```

**expected output**

```
[
{
  "_id" : "5d401d4aba592260507479d2",
  "name" : "test agency",
  "msisdn" : "99961110278",
  "apps" : [
    {
      "pincodes" : [
        "135001",
        "122017"
      ],
      "_id" : "5d401d4aba592260507479d3",
      "name" : "DSB"
    }
  ],
  "__v" : 0
}
,
{
  "_id" : "5d402249035f3063657240a9",
  "name" : "test agency",
  "msisdn" : "99961110278",
  "apps" : [
    {
      "pincodes" : [
        "135001",
        "122017"
      ],
      "_id" : "5d402249035f3063657240ab",
      "name" : "DSB"
    }
  ],
  "__v" : 0
}
,
{
  "_id" : "5d402d36035f3063657240ac",
  "name" : "test agency",
  "msisdn" : "99961110278",
  "apps" : [
    {
      "pincodes" : [
        "135001",
        "122018"
      ],
      "_id" : "5d402d36035f3063657240ae",
      "name" : "DSB"
    }
  ],
  "__v" : 0
}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) to do this.

```
db.Agency.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      apps: {
        $filter: {
           input: "$apps",
           as: "app",
           cond: {"$$app.name": {$regex: 'DSB', $options: 'i'} ,"$$app.pincodes": { $in : ['135001','134002']}}
        }
     }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: could you please explain query ..!!  little bit

Comment: Refer to the doc, this query "Selects a subset of an array to return based on the specified condition", in this case the condition is `{"$$app.name": {$regex: 'DSB', $options: 'i'} ,"$$app.pincodes": { $in : ['135001','134002']}}`. `input` is the `apps` field and `as` "represents each individual element of the input array".

Answer (score 1):

You can do in another way too by `$group` and `$match`.

```
db.getCollection('test').aggregate([
  {$match: {"apps.name": {$regex: 'DSB', $options: 'i'}}}, // Return only data which name is DSB
  {$unwind: "$apps"}, // Convert array to object (To remove DTH data in same document)
  {$match: {"apps.name": {$regex: 'DSB', $options: 'i'}, // Again filter with DSB and pincodes "apps.pincodes": { $in : ['135001','134002']}}},
  {$group: { // Finall group it again. So we will have only DSB related data
    _id: "$_id",
    name: {$first: "$name"},
    msisdn: {$first: "$msisdn"},
    __v: {$first: "$__v"},
    apps: {$push: "$apps"}
  }}
])
```

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB would return the complete array if any of the element in the array matches the condition. If you just need the matched element, you would need to use aggregation on data. The following query can get you the expected output:

```
db.agency.aggregate([
    {
        $unwind:"$apps"
    },
    {
        $match:{
            "apps.name":{
                $regex: "DSB", 
                $options: 'i'
            },
            "apps.pincodes": { 
                $in : ['135001','134002']
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $group:{
            "_id":"$_id",
            "name":{
                $first:"$name"
            },
            "msisdn":{
                $first:"$msisdn"
            },
            "apps":{
                $push:"$apps"
            },
            "__v":{
                $first:"$__v"
            }
        }
    }
]).pretty()
```

- Stage I: Opens up the array and creates individual documents for each array element
- Stage II: Applying condition
- Stage III: Grouping information again on the basis of _id